# Change Image in Unity using Image component of Canvas don't Work

Tags: unity-game-engine

I literally lost all hope in humanity. I've been trying to change an image in Unity for 3 days, I want to put an image of an item. But it just doesn't work. My Code:

```
void Update()
{
    //Press space to change the Sprite of the Image
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        m_Image = GetComponent<Image>(); 
        GetComponent<Image>().sprite = (Resources.Load<Sprite>("/WeaponsSprites/Sword"));
    }
}

public void ChangeWeaponImage() {
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `But it just doesn't work` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Hello let's discuss your code

```
m_Image = GetComponent<Image>(); 
GetComponent<Image>().sprite = (Resources.Load<Sprite>("/WeaponsSprites/Sword"));
```

In the first line, you let `m_Image` hold the Component `Image`, I'm not sure `m_Image` is a GameObject or something else I can't see any information in your code.

The problem is in the second line, your change spite didn't let Unity know which Gameobject or Something else you want to change.

you should put the first and the second lines together, I think that is what you want to do.

like this example

```
m_Image.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("/WeaponsSprites/Sword");
```

Comment: Not really actually ... `The problem is in the second line , your change spite didn't let Unity know which Gameobject or Something else you want to change.` .. yes it does .. it is the exact same reference returned by `GetComponent<Image>()` in the first line -> the `Image` component attached to the same GameObject as this script. Assuming that `m_Image` already **is** an `Image` then using `m_Image.GetComponent<Image>()` makes no sense at all .. either you already have that reference anyway or you get an exception

Comment: @derHugo you're right ,If `m_Image` already is an Image then no necessary to use `GetComponent<Image>`